# Passing a string to a database with ToUpper? VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to validate a textbox. If user enters all lower case characters then convert it to all upper case. So when its added to the database its all upper case. I need help with my function, I don't know if its a syntax error or something, here it is. I'm using VB.Net 2010

```
Public Function CheckLetters(ByVal strIn As String) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strOne As String

    For i = 0 To Len(strIn) - 1

        strOne = strIn.Substring(i, 1).ToUpper
        Select Case strOne

            Case "A" To "Z"
            Case Else

                Return False
        End Select
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: If your question is about VB.NET, the VB6 and VBA tags don't apply; they're not the same thing, and can't all apply at once. Also, your actual question is unclear - what exactly is the part you need us to help you with? You've posted a vague requirement (something about converting lower case to upper case and a database, but your code seems to be doing something character by character, except you don't explain exactly what it is you want to do, and no database is accessed in your code). Also, regardless of which VB you're using, the `microsoft` tag isn't needed.

Comment: You know you can just use "For Each" on a string, and you get the individual characters, right?

Comment: What do you want to do is some letters are lower case and some are upper case?

Comment: Ken White, I see, I will remember this next time, my first time posting. I want to convert i = 0 to 0 to all UpperCase then the rest of the string to all lower case. So if the user types in 'lastname' it will save into the database that I am hooked up to, too 'Lastname'. I just used this function as an example but I see that it's not a very good one.

Comment: So what you're actually asking is to convert it to proper case (`lastname` to `LastName', 'smith` to `Smith`)? In other words, you want the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want. I thought a case would work, but now that I understand cases more, I don't know thats the case? there isn't a proper case in VB is there? I'ved tried it...

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout this:

```
Return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, "^[a-z]*$")
```

or this

```
Return strIn.All(Function(c) Char.IsLower(c))
```

There's no good reason for this method to be anything other than a one-liner. But if you really want to loop through the characters:

```
For Each c As Char In strIn
   If Not Char.IsLower(c) Then Return False
Next c
Return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs just fine here (VB does not require the brackets after ToUpper, but it's good for readability) - it accepts a string and returns True if that string only contains the characters "A" through "Z", false otherwise. The function doesn't convert anything - just returns that Boolean result.

If you want to actually convert the string to upper case, just use .ToUpper() on the string itself, e.g.

```
Dim MyString As String = "Contains some text"

MyString = MyString.ToUpper()

' Above would set MyString to "CONTAINS SOME TEXT"
```

Comment: Oh, so the code that I have does not convert anything? I want to CONVERT it too all caps. Thanks, perhaps I shouldn't use a select case?

Comment: If you want to convert to all caps, just call ToUpper() on the string directly - that will return your original string but all letters upper case.

Comment: If instead you want to convert to title case (first letter upper case in most cultures), use TextInfo.ToTitleCase:

`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("some text")`

.. which would yield "Some text".